# Como acessar um array e exportar as variáveis?

Tags: php, array, variáveis

Tenho um código que recebe os dados via `$_POST` de um formulário da seguinte forma:

```
...
$certificate = $_POST['certificate'];
...
```

Se fizer um `print_r($certificate)` o resultado é o seguinte:

```
Array (
        ['cliente'] => White Martins Gases Industriais Ltda 
        ['entrega'] => 2017-04-11
        ['utilizacao'] => Oxigênio
        ['norma'] => White Martins - PR029
      )
```

Os campos no form estão da seguinte forma:

```
<select type="select" class="form-control" name="certificate['cliente']" id="cliente">
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="certificate['entrega']" id="entrega"> 
<select type="select" class="form-control" name="certificate['utilizacao']" id="utilizacao">
<select type="select" class="form-control" name="certificate['norma']" id="norma">
```

Como atribuir os valores desse array em 4 variáveis separadas, tipo:

```
$cliente = ????;
$entrega = ????;
$utilizacao = ????;
$norma = ????;
```

Não estou sabendo acessar o array.

Comment: Os campos no form estão da seguinte forma:  

<select type="select" class="form-control" name="certificate['cliente']" id="cliente">  

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="certificate['entrega']" id="entrega">  

<select type="select" class="form-control" name="certificate['utilizacao']" id="utilizacao">  

<select type="select" class="form-control" name="certificate['norma']" id="norma">  

Dessa forma quando é feito o submit, é enviado para a página um array com todos os dados do form, mas não consigo acessar de forma alguma.

Comment: Não consigo acessar os índices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `list()`. Porém, como não utiliza indexes numéricos você precisará utilizar o `array_values`, como por exemplo:

```
list($cliente, $entrega, $utilizacao, $norma) = array_values($_POST['certificate']);
```

[Teste isto aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ad6a0626817f1da162ac7c2046afb8304d29135).

Então poderá utilizar `$cliente`, `$entrega` normalmente.

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de acessar o conteudo, seria informando o nome do array,e o seu indice, dessa forma:

```
echo $certificate['cliente'];
```

Outra forma tambem seria usando o [extract](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php) , que realiza a função que voce quer, de extrair o conteúdo e transforma em variáveis, dessa forma:

```
 extract($certificate);
 echo $cliente;
```

Um exemplo bem simples para seu caso, usando array:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post"><select type="select" class="form-control" name="certificate[]" id="cliente" value="cliente">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="certificate[entrega]" id="entrega" value="entrega"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="certificate[utilizacao]" value="utilizacao">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Ai no PHP, voce pegaria os dados da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
    $certificate=$_POST['certificate'];
    echo $certificate['entrega'];
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: cliente in C:\xampp\htdocs\lince\certificates\pdf.php on line 4

Comment: @FlávioKowalske Não resolveu ainda? Nenhuma das formas deu certo?

Comment: @FlávioKowalske vi ali como estão os names dos inputs/selects... deixa eles sem o `certificate` deixe somente `<select type="select" class="form-control" name="cliente" id="cliente">`

Comment: Lembrando que o `extract` pode ser perigoso, a primeira solução (assim como a do @Divoso é mais segura). Recomendo que leia sobre isto em https://davidnoren.com/post/php-extract-vulnerability.html.

Comment: @LocalHost nada deu certo....

Comment: @LocalHost testei aqui da forma que vc sugeriu, e deu certo, porém preciso pegar as variáveis uma por uma do outro lado. a ideia é pegar o array com todas...

Comment: @FlávioKowalske Entendi, vou ver se consigo fazer um exemplo aqui, e ja coloco...

Comment: @FlávioKowalske dá uma olhada agora... Se é isso, marque como resposta...

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou assim?

```
$cliente = $certificate['cliente'];
$entrega = $certificate['entrega'];
$utilizacao = $certificate['utilizacao'];
$norma = $certificate['norma'];
```

Comment: Dá o seguinte erro:

    Notice: Undefined index: cliente in C:\xampp\htdocs\lince\certificates\pdf.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: entrega in C:\xampp\htdocs\lince\certificates\pdf.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: utilizacao in C:\xampp\htdocs\lince\certificates\pdf.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: norma in C:\xampp\htdocs\lince\certificates\pdf.php on line 6